# Python 3.6 Messy String with Unicode characters and Bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

So I am taking articles titles from the Common Crawl news repo using NewsPlease, but when I take the articles titles, but they are a mixture of normally encoded characters and Unicode bytes, and I am unable to get it encoded correctly.  Taking one of the titles:

```py
x = articles[800].title
```

If I call x in spyder, it returns:

```py
'Las 10 canciones m\\xc3\\xa1s populares de la semana'
```

When I use
`print(x)`
I get:

```
Las 10 canciones m\xc3\xa1s populares de la semana
```

BUT if try to correctly encode it using: (As other posts suggest)

```py
x.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

It returns

```py
'Las 10 canciones m\\xc3\\xa1s populares de la semana'
```

Which is obviously not correct.

Anyone have any suggestions? I am using Python 3.6 by the way

Comment: I'm fairly sure you already messed something up when you fetched this data; I have a hard time believing that the data set originally contained a string representation of hex characters. How did you initialize `articles`?

Comment: I can't post the full code, but the issue is the from_warc() method of Newsplease, that's the format it returns data in when pulling from a common crawl WARC.  Articles is just a list of NewsPlease article objects.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this:

```
x = 'this is a test of the Spanish word m\\xc3\\xa1s'
x = x.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
print(x)
'this is a test of the Spanish word más'
```